# Differential Equation - Blood Alcohol

Tags: mathematical-modeling

Let C(t) be the concentration of alcohol in a person's bloodstream. We propose a mathematical model which states that, once a person stops drinking alcohol, C decreases at a rate that is proportional to C. Write down a differential equation consistent with that model.

Comment: Hint: the rate of decrease is the derivative of $C$ and is negative when the concentration is positive

Comment: Another Hint: saying that a function $f$ is proportional to a function $g$ means that there exists some $\alpha \in \Bbb{R}$ such that $f=\alpha g$. Next look at @marwalix solution, if you don't get it by yourself :D

Answer (score 1):

And the solution is $$\frac{dC(t)}{dt}=-\alpha C(t)$$ where $\alpha \gt 0$. Solving the equation we have $$C(t)=C(0)\exp{(-\alpha t)}$$

Comment: Are you sure? At $t=0$ your solution is $0$! So the person is sober. :-)

Comment: Sorry typo corrected